# Android Nested RecyclerView Change Angle Of Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have horizontal recyclerViews in vertical RecyclerView.  [image] To scroll horizontally I should swipe from 45 degrees to -45 degree. To scroll vertically from 90 degrees to 45 degrees. Is any possibility to override this?

For example, vertical scroll works only with the swipe from 105 to 75 degrees. Else, horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `MainVerticalRecyclerView` like this:

```
open class MainVerticalRecyclerView : RecyclerView {

    private var scrollPointerId = -1
    private var pointTouchX = 0
    private var pointTouchY = 0
    private var touchSlopType = 0

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        val vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context)
        touchSlopType = vc.scaledTouchSlop
    }

    override fun setScrollingTouchSlop(slopConstant: Int) {
        super.setScrollingTouchSlop(slopConstant)

        val vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context)
        when (slopConstant) {
            TOUCH_SLOP_DEFAULT -> touchSlopType = vc.scaledTouchSlop
            TOUCH_SLOP_PAGING -> touchSlopType = vc.scaledPagingTouchSlop
        }
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (e == null) {
            return false
        }

        val action = e.actionMasked
        val actionIndex = e.actionIndex

        when (action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                scrollPointerId = e.getPointerId(0)
                pointTouchX = Math.round(e.x + 0.5f)
                pointTouchY = Math.round(e.y + 0.5f)
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> {
                scrollPointerId = e.getPointerId(actionIndex)
                pointTouchX = Math.round(e.getX(actionIndex) + 0.5f)
                pointTouchY = Math.round(e.getY(actionIndex) + 0.5f)
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val index = e.findPointerIndex(scrollPointerId)
                if (index < 0) {
                    return false
                }

                val x = Math.round(e.getX(index) + 0.5f)
                val y = Math.round(e.getY(index) + 0.5f)
                if (scrollState != SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    val dx = x - pointTouchX
                    val dy = y - pointTouchY
                    var startScroll = false
                    if (layoutManager?.canScrollHorizontally() == true && Math.abs(dx) > touchSlopType && (layoutManager?.canScrollVertically() == true || Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy))) {
                        startScroll = true
                    }
                    if (layoutManager?.canScrollVertically() == true && Math.abs(dy) > touchSlopType && (layoutManager?.canScrollHorizontally() == true || Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx))) {
                        startScroll = true
                    }
                    return startScroll && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
                }
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
            }
            else -> {
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and create `ChildHorizontalRecyclerView` for other nested `RecyclerView` inside main `RecyclerView` like this:

```
class ChildHorizontalRecyclerView : MainVerticalRecyclerView {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
}
```

if you want scroll like in `PlayStore` when you touch `HorizontalChildRecyclerView` need write:

```
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
            override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}
            override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                if (e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && rv.scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    rv.stopScroll()
                }
                return false
            }

            override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
        })
```